# from the moment vs after

Tags: sentence-construction

> 1.Explain about what you usually do from the moment you wake up and to the moment you go to sleep.
>
> 2.Explain about what you usually do after you wake up and until you go to sleep.

my humble personal opinion is that from the moment = after / to the moment = until

But I'm not sure if I can use whichever I want to in any situations. Am I right to think this way?

Answer (score 1):

They are roughly synonymous, but "from/to the moment" is more precise and emphatic. In the instructions you give, the first form is requiring more information - everything you did, instead of just the most noticeable things. Would you mention turning off your alarm clock? Taking your medicine? Making your bed? Maybe, maybe not. But the first is asking for those in a way that the second is probably not.

In practice, depending on context, there might not be any practical difference; but there might be.

Answer (score 0):

Your interpretation is correct. "from" means the beginning or origin of something (be it a person, thing, or period of time). "until" means the end or conclusion of something.

"I waited until it stopped raining to go outside"
Means that when the rain ended, the person speaking went outside.

"I waited from when it stopped raining to go outside"
This sounds odd - but the meaning is the opposite of above. It means that the person speaking **started** to wait to go outside **after** it stopped raining.

The two words are not at all interchangeable.